# Issue with using shared_ptr with custom equality operator and STL

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, comparison-operators

There seems to be an issue when using shared pointers together with a custom equality operator and an std::list.

I put together the following example code to demonstrate the issue.

Before trying to compile this:

I'm using `gcc version 4.5.2 20110127`

with the following commandline:

`g++ -g -O0 -std=gnu++0x test.cpp`

The source won't compile if c++0x features aren't enabled.

```
#include<list>
#include<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using std::list;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class TestInt
{
   public:
      TestInt(int x);
      bool operator==(const TestInt& other);

   private:
      int _i;
};

TestInt::TestInt(int x)
{
   _i = x;
}

bool
TestInt::operator==(const TestInt& other)
{
   if (_i == other._i){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

class Foo
{
   public:
      Foo(TestInt i);
      shared_ptr<TestInt> f(TestInt i);

   private:
      list<shared_ptr<TestInt>> _x;
};

Foo::Foo(TestInt i)
{
   _x.push_back(shared_ptr<TestInt>(new TestInt(i)));
};

shared_ptr<TestInt>
Foo::f(TestInt i)
{
   shared_ptr<TestInt> test(new TestInt(i));
   int num = _x.size();
   list<shared_ptr<TestInt>>::iterator it = _x.begin();
   for (int j=0; j<num; ++j){
      if (test == *it){
         return test;
      }
      ++it;
   }
   throw "Error";
}

int main(){
   TestInt ti(5);
   TestInt ti2(5);
   Foo foo(ti);
   foo.f(ti2);
   std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
}
```

I would have expected that the code finishes with `Success` but instead it throws.

Inserting a `*` infront of `test` as well as `*it` fixes the issue but my understanding is that when the shared_ptr calles `__a.get() == __b.get()` in its `==` operator it should use the custom equality operator of `TestInt`. I don't understand why it is not. Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the `{}` button in the editor to format code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because when you compare two `shared_ptr<T>`, you are comparing the *reference*, that is, the memory address that the two instances point to, *not* the underlying values.

Comment: Not true. As I pointed out in my post shared_ptr compares by default `__a.get() == __b.get` which should in principle compare the underlying objects.
And it actually does that if I'm not using a std::list for example. But in this case it fails.

Comment: shared_ptr::get() returns a pointer to the referenced object, not a reference to it.  DeadMG's answer is correct.

Comment: sorry, my bad.
Confused em with policy based smart_ptr (http://www.axter.com/smartptr/classsmart__ptr.htm) which have value_comparsion_semantic_policy as the default.

Answer (score 3):

You're not comparing TestInt objects but rather two different pointers each pointing to its own TestInt object. So essentially your custom equals operator is not even called.

What you're doing is basically:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int* pi1 = new int(5);
    int* pi2 = new int(5);
    if (pi1 == pi2)
        std::cout << "SUCCESS";
    else 
        std::cout << "ERROR";
}
```

Now it should be obvious that pi1 and pi2 are not equal and the code finishes printing ERROR.

(The fact that I have used a raw pointer instead of a shared_ptr doesn't change anything, but makes the logic easier to understand. Same with using int directly instead of using a wrapper class for it.)